# How do I delete a single product from a Facebook Catalog Product feed?

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

The catalog has aprox. 150K products, so we are looking for an automated way to do this every time we delete a product from our store. Ideally through the Marketing API.

Comment: Please improve your question.

Comment: Hi Ved, thanks for your reply. When we delete a product from our store, we want this change to be reflected in our Facebook Catalog. Basically deleting the correspondent item from the product catalog in Facebook.
How de we do this?

Comment: Have you tried this https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.cpcstrategy.com/blog/2015/06/how-to-set-up-a-facebook-product-catalog-upload-a-feed/amp/